# Practice Hadoop?

Tags: data-request, big-data

Can someone guide me in how to learn and practice Hadoop? I want to work on big data in the future and I want to work further in the field. Some datasets, practice tutorials, and guidelines are what I am looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you are:

A [MOOC](https://www.coursera.org/course/datasci) from coursera, but you have to wait until they will run it again or

You can start from dozens of courses [here](http://bigdatauniversity.com/courses/) in big data university.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to educational materials, Cloudera offers a free Hadoop cluster that is ready to go. After installing [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), KVM or VMWare, you can download and run the virtual machine.

- [link](http://www.cloudera.com/quickstartvm)
- [blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/01/how-to-create-a-simple-hadoop-cluster-with-virtualbox/)
- [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CobVqNMiqww)

Hortonworks also offers a complete VM: "[sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/). This comes with Hive, Pig, and other tools that can be managed by the browser frontend.

- [Download and install](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/#install)
- [Tutorials](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/#tutorial_gallery)

[image]

[image]